# MySQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following code to list the jid and count.

```
Select jid,count(jid) as jidtime 
From Application
Group by jid;
```

[image]

but I also want to show the jid and the max(jidtime),which is jid:4 jidtime:6

I tried, but fail. Need some help...

```
Select jid, max(jidtime) 
From (Select jid,count(jid) as jidtime From Application
Group by jid) AS T;
```

Comment: You mean you just want to show the row where jidtime is max(jidtime)?

Comment: Wouldn't you just run `Select jid,count(jid) as jidtime From Application Group by jid ORDER BY jidtime DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @developerwjk:yes, or only show the jid of the one with max value

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with `order by` and `limit`:

```
Select jid, count(jid) as jidtime 
From Application a
Group by jid
Order by count(jid) desc
Limit 1;
```

This takes the results, orders them by the second column, and then limits the query to the first row (which should have the highest value).

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery in an in-clause:

```
Select * from Application
WHERE jidtime IN (Select Max(jidtime) From Application)
```

Or just order by descending, and limit, which should be faster:

```
Select * from Application order by jidtime desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have two options. i cant give the excat (tested) code becasue i dont have a mssql right now.

one is something with rank, i dont know the correct code now, but it should be like

```
 select jid, count(jid) OVER (PARTITION BY jid order by count(jid)) 
 from Application 
 group by jid
```

the second option is with a subquery.

```
select jid, count(jid) as jidtime 
from Application
group by jid
having count(jid) = (select max(count(jid) 
                         from Application 
                         group by jid
                     )
```